# Changing size of png situated on ggplot in r

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, png, shapes

```
img2 <- png::readPNG("IGCE.png")
shape <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/Владимир/Desktop/ИГКЭ/QGIS", layer = "ne_50m_land")

rast <- grid::rasterGrob(img2, interpolate = T)

ggplot()+
geom_polygon(data = g, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = NA)+
coord_fixed(xlim = c(4000000, 12000000),  ylim = c(3000000, 8000000))+
annotation_custom(rast)
```

thats is the result I have got. 
[image]I made one picture with shape file in ggplot2:

How should I make second picture change size? It should be smaller. 
[This is may picture](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/QseZ/2v5nULFhC)
[It is the shape](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_land.zip)